# char arrays in C and compare

Tags: c, arrays, char

I've got some problems with char arrays in C.

I've got two arrays:

```
char history[10][80];
char *args[80];
```

And I also got a `char inputBuffer[80]` (this contains one string).
What I would like to do is to find out if the value in `*args` exists in `history`.

I fill up `history` like this (`histCount` is between 0 and 10).

```
for(j=0; j<MAX_LINE; j++)
{
    history[histCount][j] = inputBuffer[j];
}
```

What I can't figure out is how I can loop through `history` to see if it matches `args[]`.

1. Example If `args[0] == 'romeo'` and `history[3][0] == 'r'` then match.
2. If `args[0] == 'selfie'` and `history[7][0] == 's'` then match.

My first idea was to do something like this, but it doesn’t seem to work

```
for(k=0; k<10; k++) {
    if(args[1] == history[k]) {
        printf("FOUND!!\n");
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your sample condition list isn't correct. `args[0]` is a `char*`, `history[3][0]` is a `char`. Likewise for the second example. It seems you're trying to match the string at `args[n]` against the string at `history[m]`. If all you want is a single-char-match you're going to need another indirection on `args`.

Comment: @WhozCraig You are right. `args[1]` is a `char*`, while `history[3][0]`is a char. What do I need to do to be able to check these against each other?

Comment: Your question exhibits no indication as to your intent of the kind of check you want. Again, if you only want to check the first char of each string, `(args[n][0] == history[m][0])`. If you want to check for full matching of the strings, `(strcmp(args[n], history[m]) == 0)`, in both cases appropriate indices for `n` and `m` to match the problem you're solving.

Comment: @WhozCraig I do want to only check the first char of each string. The problem is that `args[1]` is a `char*` while `history[n][m]` is a `char` (as you said). For example; `args[1]` could be 'hello', while `history[n][0] could be 'h' - and then I want it to be a match.

Comment: Yeah, then the former (first) of the two examples in my prior comment is likely what you're looking for, which checks only the first char of each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not 100% sure I understand. args[0] is a pointer, which can be interpreted as a string. Which is not what you want in your example. You want args[0] to be a single char.

```
int main ( void ) {
    char history[10][80]
    char *args[80]

    int i, j, k;

    // filling
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_LINE; ++i) {
        history[histCount][i] = inputBuffer[i]; // this can be achieved with strcpy();
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        for (j = 0; j < 80; ++j) {
            for (k = j; k < 80; ++k) {
            if (history[i][j] == args[0][k]) {
                printf ("FOUND!!");
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What it does is initiating  history as a 2D char array and args as a char array. Then for every row it compares the j index of history with the k index of args.

For the sake of it. A short demo.

```
        history[0]   args
0,0     a            b
0,1     a            a
0,2     a            d
```

history[0][0] will find the same character at args[1]

Comment: Thanks, thats almost what I need. The only thing is that I need `char *args[]` to be a pointer elsewhere in the code. So, is there a way I can check the first character of a pointer against another character? (by doing the for-loops as you described above, only with `*args[]` )

Comment: What do you need it to be a pointer for? I can maybe help with that. You can use args[] as a pointer (Note! It is not the exact same thing). But you can change to args[0][k] in the compare line.

Comment: I only check the first char of each "string". The problem is that `args[1]` is a `char*` while `history[n][m]` is a `char`. For example; `args[1]` could be 'hello', while `history[n][0] could be 'h' - and then I want it to be a match.

Comment: Do as I said above, args[0][k] will do the trick then. history[n] can also be taken for a char pointer. I will update my example. Updated it.

Comment: Getting closer, I think :) Is there anything I should include to avoid getting match on \0 at the end? I seem to be getting a match now no mather what I type..

Answer (score 2):

```
for(k=0; k<10; k++)
{
    if(strcmp(args[1],history[k]) == 0)
    {
        printf("FOUND!!");
    }
}
```